# Synonym Request

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

I was reviewing some questions and came across [toc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/toc) and wondered what it was, so I clicked on it. Mostly I'm writing this to meet *quality standards*

[toc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/toc) (**6 questions**) should be a synonym of [table-of-contents](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/table-of-contents) (**14 questions**)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
updating post history, 10 rows affected
updating posts, 9 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 5 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [table-of-contents] and [toc] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym toc -> table-of-contents was approved!
```

Comment: el Gracias Señor!

Comment: Denada, mi amigo.